# How can i get images from response json in dropbox

Tags: php, json, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I want to retrieve all the images stored in my dropbox account .I try Many Solutions But i can't retrive images . Images are located in folders on Dropbox account . Can Any One Please Help me Out ??

```
$session = new DropboxSession(
    $config["dropbox"]["app_key"], 
    $config["dropbox"]["app_secret"], 
    $config["dropbox"]["access_type"], 
    $access_token
);
$client = new DropboxClient($session);

$path = (!empty($_GET["path"])) ? $_GET["path"] : "/";
// List contents of home directory
if ($home = $client->get_files($path)) {
    echo "<p>Metadata content for <code>" . $path . "</code></p>";
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($home, true) . "</pre>";
}
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<strong>ERROR (" . $e->getCode() . ")</strong>: " . $e->getMessage();
    if ($e->getCode() == 401) 
    {
     // Remove auth file
     unlink($config["app"]["authfile"]);
     // Re auth
     echo '<p><a href="authorize.php">Click Here to re-authenticate</a></p>';
    }
 }
```

And Here is The DROPBOX Client Function .

```
   public function get_files($path, $hash = null, $revision = null) {
    // Prepare argument list
    $args = array(
        "hash" => $hash,
        "rev" => $revision
    );
    // Prepend the right access string to the desired path
    if ("dropbox" == $this->accessType) {
        $path = "auto" . $path;
    }
    else {
        $path = "sandbox" . $path;
    }

    // Execute
        $response = $this->Session->fetch("GET", $this->dropboxAPIURL,    "/shares/" . $path, $args);
    return $response["body"];
}
```

Error : dropbox/Photos Not Found 
Any Idea ???

Comment: You're already including auto/ as the root in the path, so you don't need to include 'dropbox/' or 'sandbox/' too.

Comment: its still not working

Comment: Please update your post with the a sample request and response showing the full error then.

Comment: Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [path] => The root path ("/") is not allowed.
        )

)

Comment: i need all the images which are present in my dropbox . Is this correct way to fetch data ??

Comment: The error message indicates that you're attempting to get a shared link for your root Dropbox folder, which isn't allowed. Make sure your `$path` variable contains the path to the desired non-root file or folder you want a link for.

Comment: @Greg Do You Know any other way ??